# Mvc razor bundles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I created a layout in ASP.NET MVC, and I used a script bundle for loading jQuery library, but jQuery is not loaded.

My layout looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and my bundle file is

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Please help me !

Comment: how does your server side code look like?

Comment: +1... need to see your BundleConfig.cs. And why do you think it's not being loaded? Maybe show an example of how you're using jQuery in your views.

Comment: Post you bundles (your code above is fine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code in question is correct i.e you are including bundles correctly,there may be problem in your bundleconfig file or you are not including bundles correctly in view.

Use `@section scripts{ }` in `.cshtml` `Views` as shown :-

```
 @section scripts{
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

     });
   </script>
 }
```

Comment: in layout can not use script section

Comment: @MehdiHaghshenas..i think questioner is getting trouble laoding bundles in views not in layout.

Comment: if want to use scripts more than one time what to do?

Comment: sorry i m not getting you..Mehdi Haghshenas

Comment: @MehdiHaghshenas answer worked good but for loading page faster i remove it.

Comment: @mehrdad....yes..its a very bad practice to include js files in head...in your question you are including js files correctly just above closing body tag